# I need to give a div the same width than its parent.parent div with css

Tags: html, css

I need the `div` with an id of `#my-div` to have the same width as the `div` with an id of `#wrapper` using just css:

html

```
<div  id="wrapper"> <!-- width is 100% of the browser -->
    <div  id="content"> <!-- width is 940px -->
        <div  id="my-div"></div> <!-- width should be 100% of the brower -->
    </div>      
</div>
```

I tried with this css

```
#content{width: 940px; margin:0 auto;}
#my-div{margin: 0px -100%; padding: 0px 100% ;}
```

but not working.

Comment: Please link to the code running, it might be a better idea. jsfiddle.net or codepen.io EDIT: Sry, didn't see the snippets

Comment: This markup and your stated goal seem to indicate that your markup is not semantically representing the structure of the content. You should probably be moving "my-div" out of "content"

Comment: Flow it out of the second div using float/position

Comment: Adding to what @unobf said your `my-div` is trying to assume 100% the width of `content` because that is `my-div`'s parent.

Comment: I can't not change the html structure.

Comment: Then the only way you can do this is with JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know this can be possible is just taking the `#my-div` out of the flow with `absolute` position, but this will have consequences on the content of `#content`:

```css
* {margin:0}
html,body {height:100%;}
#wrapper {
  height:100%;
  background:#eee;
  position:relative;
}
#content {
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
  height:50%;
  background:red;
}
#my-div {
  height:20%;
  background:orange;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  top:10%;
}
```

```html
<div  id="wrapper"> <!-- width is 100% of the browser -->
    <div  id="content"> <!-- width is 940px -->
        <div  id="my-div"></div> <!-- width should be 100% of the brower -->
    </div>      
</div>
```

---

Now this solves the situation but maybe isn't the best approach for your goal.... You can try to explain better and perhaps I can give you another solution for what you want.

Comment: I need to use this css for #content: #content{width: 940px; margin:0 auto;}

Comment: @JPashs is exact the same as the snippet I just change the width to fit the preview as an example.

Comment: It didn't work, but it is due to the structure of my html tags. Your code is right.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give my-div position:absolute

```
    #my-div
    {
            width:100%;
            height:20px;
            min-width:600px;
            background-color:red;
            position:absolute;
            left:0;
            right:0;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only way to do this is to give the #my-div div a `position:absolute`.

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
width:100%;
position:relative;
}

#content {
width:940px;
margin:0 auto;
}

#my-div {
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
```

}

But this will take the div out of the flow, meaning other elements won't be adjusted noticing this div thus repositioning can be required so elements won't flow underneath the absolute positioned one.

Be sure not to put a `position:relative` to the #content div, otherwise the absolute div will be positioned to the left of its parent.

Please see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/djsyxkzz/ for an example

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use negative margins to make it bigger than it's parent. You can't use percentages (at least to my knowledge). Is there a specific reason you have something you want 100% wide in a fixed size div?

```
#my-div{margin:0px -3000px;}
```